# How to embed all fonts in pdf generated from pdflatex

Tags: fonts, pdf, latex

I am using pdflatex in Ubuntu to generate pdf files. While, it didn't pass the check due to missing of fonts. The online suggestions includes:

1. pdf-ps-pdf:
   thois one can ruin the original file. The pdf looks terrible.
2. use latex-dvips-...:
   This one has a problem with the image size.
3. use adobe reader, manually include those fonts:
   adobe reader does not exist on Ubuntu

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

An easy way exist with system viewer in ubuntu.
Open your pdf with system viewer. Go to tap file->print
select print to file then print. Now you get it. The generated one includes all fonts. You can check with command pdffonts

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of posts on this in the tex help forum

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275715/how-to-compile-with-embedded-font-in-latex-and-preserve-figures

Your 3 options are not great, maybe will not help. I'd use ghostsscript, but don't know if it fits your case.

I am surprised you hit this now.  what version pdflatex you using? Fonts are embedded on new version of pdflatex..

However, fonts may be missing in included image files. And you fix those files separately. For example,  if you use includes of pdf from R, fonts are not embedded in them and you need fix graphic files, not the pdflatex doc that holds them. I have fixed this recently with ghostscript. I would not consider any other way.

I suppose the particular fonts might make a difference.

A REPRODUCIBLE example is customary in case like this. Gather details and go ask on tex.stackexchange.

Added in edit:

Here's a shell script I run that uses ghostscript to insert fonts in all pdf files within a directory. I called it
embedFontInPDF.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

## Paul Johnson
## 2013-05-11
##
## R creates pdf files that do not have fonts embedded. This
## uses ghostscript to fix that. It takes all pdf in a directory
## and embeds fonts.
##
## Todo: Make command line argument smarter

for i in *.pdf; do
    base=`basename $i .pdf`;
    basenew="${base}/newtemp.pdf"

   /usr/bin/gs -o $basenew -dNOPAUSE -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress     -sDEVICE=pdfwrite $i

    mv -f $basenew $i
done;
```